# Computing a conditional expectation function from data set

Tags: conditional-expectation

Say I have a two dimensional numerical data scatter $(x_i,y_i)$ corresponding to variables $x,y$, and I want to estimate the conditional expectation $\langle x|y\rangle$, what would be the procedure to do this?

I thought about splitting the range of $y$ into equally sized bins, and compute the mean of $x_i$ for each of the bins. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: to help with your googling, the practice of computing a conditional expectation is called "Regression Analysis". There are many approaches, and which one is best depends on the many details of your data currently left out of the question.